# Javascript date object confusion

Tags: javascript

The question on my homework is this:

> Create a function called dateUS( ).
>
> This function will accept a Date object as a parameter. It will return a string in the following format 'mm/dd/yyyy' based upon the value of the parameter.

The code I have written is this:

```
function getMonth(today) {
  var inMo = today.getMonth();  
  inMo += 1;        
  return inMo;                      
}

function dateUS(inDate) {
  document.write(getMonth(today) + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear());
}
```

I don't understand what "inDate" is doing in this code? And I'm wondering if that is why I'm getting an output of this: `5/7/2014undefined`

I don't understand the "accepting a Date object as a parameter" can someone explain? Keep it simple please. This is a Javascript 101 class and I'm just learning. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is it you who wrote this code? What do you have about custom function declarations and arguments in your lectures?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `today`?

Comment: I wrote the code with the teacher in class. don't have anything about custom functions declarations or arguments. I've been online to w3schools and I've read that what is in the parenthesis is the argument, but I don't completely understand what that means.

Comment: I think `undefined` is coming from some other part of your program, not this code. Maybe the function that calls `dateUS` is doing it.

Comment: Functions have arguments so you can tell them to operate on different data. `inDate` is the date that the function should write, instead of only being able to write today's date.

Comment: I set the variable today in the head of my html, just after my first script tag

Comment: so should inDate be defined in my code as a variable?

Comment: you should probably learn the basics of JavaScript before asking here.

Comment: I'm in a class learning the basics, and needed additional help with it. but thanks anyway

Comment: This is my first time using stackoverflow, guess it's not useful for those of us just learning. Will go somewhere else

Comment: For future reference, I recommend avoiding W3Schools like the plague. Virtually everything on that site is either outdated, misguided, or blatantly wrong. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Really?!?!! That is very interesting considering my teacher prefers that we use them as a trusted resource.

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters allow a function to operate on different inputs. In this case, `inDate` is the local name given to the argument supplied when you call the function. So the function should be:

```
function dateUS(inDate) {
    document.write(getMonth(dateUS) + '/' + dateUS.getDate() + '/' + dateUS.getFullYear());
}
```

If you want to write today's date, you call the function this way:

```
dateUS(today);
```

There isn't enough information in the question to explain why `undefined` is being shown after the date. My guess is you're doing something like:

```
document.write(dateUS(today));
```

This would be appropriate if `dateUS` returned its result instead of writing it itself. That probably would be a better way to define it, but it's not how you did it.

Comment: Wow! Yes, that's how I wrote it. Lol!! I'm still in the vary early stages of learning this stuff. It can get very confusing at times. Thank you for your help. I vary much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Functions can access 3 types of data:

1. Data created outside the scope of the function (global variables).
2. Data created within the function.
3. Data passed to the function as a parameter.

So if you have a function that converts a date object to a string, you either want to use a global variable (#1) or pass a date object in as a parameter (#3). You usually want to do the latter because it's more flexible and doesn't require your function to have knowledge of the code that surrounds it, which means you could use it in another project or elsewhere in your code.

For example, if you want to add two numbers, you would write this function:

```
function add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

You would call it like this: `add(5, 6);`, which would return 11.

Now, we can extend this to date objects.

```
function dateUS(date){
    return date.getDate();
}
```

This function will return what `date`'s `getDate` method returns, but you'll need to change that to fit your assignment.

```
var date1 = new Date(); // Now
var date2 = new Date(0); // The beginning of time
alert(dateUS(date1)); // Alerts 7 (or whatever day of the month it is for you)
alert(dateUS(date2)); // Alerts 31
```

The advantage of using a parameter is that we can create as many date objects as we want and our function will work for all of them.